# How to search mySql database table by foreign key using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have 2 classes (BusinessAccount and Projects (shown below) that are mapped to a MySql database) where a 1:M relationship exists between BusinessAccounts and Projects. I am successfully inserting data to the database but am having a problem when it comes to querying the database. The problem that I am having is that I have no getter or setter for the foreign key, 'contractor_id' in the Projects class. The query that I want to carry out is to return the list of the names of all projects for a given BusinessAccount, by searching by the foreign key reference in the Projects table. I can do this no problem in mySQL but as there is no reference to the contractor_id as a java entity in the Projects class, I'm not sure how to do this search from within my java class. (Note: I tried to declare the foreign key along with getters and setters in the Projects class but as I have these mapped by the 1:Many relationship in the class already, it wouldn't compile as they were flagged as duplicate entities.) I'm sure it's something obvious that I'm missing but any help is much appreciated!

```
public List<Projects> getProjectList() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
    List<Projects> projectList = new ArrayList<Projects>();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);

        List<BusinessAccount> userList=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =userList.get(0);

        Query myQuery2 = em.createQuery("SELECT distinct p.* FROM BusinessAccount u "
                + "INNER JOIN Projects p ON p.contractor_id=:userID");

/*Note p.contractor_id above refers to the entity in the 
mysql database (and won't work obviously), I want to refer 
to it's java equivalent but am not sure how to do that*/

        myQuery2.setParameter("userID", account.getId());
        projectList=myQuery2.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return projectList;

    } 


@Entity
@Table(name = "business_accounts")
public class BusinessAccount {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Projects> projects;

    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
    }

       public List<Projects> getProjects()
    {
    if (projects == null)
    {
        projects = new ArrayList<Projects>();
    }

    return projects;
    }

   public void setProjects(List<Projects> projects)
    {
    this.projects = projects;
    }

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Projects {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int project_id;

@Column(name = "project_name")
private String projectName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "contractor_id", referencedColumnName="id") })
private BusinessAccount businessAccount;


public BusinessAccount getBusinessAccount() {
    if (businessAccount == null) {
        businessAccount = new BusinessAccount();
    }
    return businessAccount;
}

public void setBusinessAccount(BusinessAccount businessAccount) {
    this.businessAccount = businessAccount;
}

public int getProject_id() {
    return project_id;
}

public void setProject_id(int project_id) {
    this.project_id = project_id;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you try this for query2? Query myQuery2 = em.createQuery("SELECT distinct p.* FROM Projects p where p.businessAccount.id=:userID");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JPA query would be something like (you need to use the relation property, but no need for the foreign key itself - please try, it may need some tweaking):

```
SELECT p FROM BusinessAccount u, IN(u.projects) p WHERE u.id=:userId
```

But do you really need the query? You can get the related projects from the property:

```
BusinessAccount account = ...
List<Projects> projectList = account.getProjects();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Nikos-appreciate it! That worked and makes so much more sense than the way I was querying the db!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, if you *had* to write a query, the solution from Gayathi's comment would be more efficient I believe.

Comment: Thanks-I'll give that a try as well for my own learning but for the purposes of what I'm doing your suggestion works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Query myQuery2 = em.createQuery("SELECT distinct p.* FROM BusinessAccount u "
            + "INNER JOIN Projects p ON p.businessAccount=:businessAccount");

myQuery2.setParameter("businessAccount", account);
```